# Compare times and dates in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to check if a time is after or before some time string. The database I have been given has times in multiple formats like `00:00:00` and `1970-01-01 07:00:00`. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
data = {some_id:1, time_1:'1970-01-01 07:00:00', time_2:'1970-01-01 07:00:00'}

    $results = $this->model->select(
        'table.value as value'
    )
        ->where('table.some_id', '=', $data['some_id'])
        ->where('table.time_1', '=>', $data['time_1'])
        ->orWhere('table.time_2', '<=', $data['time_2'])
        ->get();
```

But, this just returns every single value in the table. How do I compare dates like this when they are not technically dates?

Comment: What type of field are you using in the database for these time fields?

Comment: take note that using orWhere does not 'attach/link' to only the previous where but to the whole query meaning that if the last statement is true, BOTH the other wheres do not need to be true anymore

Comment: A TIME and a DATETIME need to be compared, and the date part of it disregarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it will return all records.

Because logic of query is not correct.

For Your query sql will be like:

```
SELECT table.value AS value 
FROM table 
WHERE 
  table.some_id = 1 
  AND 
  table.time_1 <= '1970-01-01 07:00:00' OR table.time_2 => '1970-01-01 07:00:00'
```

But it should be:

```
SELECT table.value AS value 
FROM table 
WHERE 
  table.some_id = 1 
  AND 
  (table.time_1 <= '1970-01-01 07:00:00' OR table.time_2 => '1970-01-01 07:00:00')
```

To achieve this do nested where:

```
$results = $this->model->select(
    'table.value as value'
)
    ->where('table.some_id', '=', $data['some_id'])
    ->where(function($q) use ($data) {
       return $q->where('table.time_1', '=>', $data['time_1'])
                ->orWhere('table.time_2', '<=', $data['time_2']);
    })
    ->get();
```

p.s. if it does not return proper response, I recommend to check dates that You request.

Comment: This gives me 'where' not found and 'undefined variable data'. Do you know how I would compare `07:00:00 <= '1970-01-01 07:00:00`?

Comment: I am comparing a `Time` and a `Datetime`, and need to disregard the date part of the datetime. Thanks for your help, its very clear so far.

Comment: What if I have only time in the database like 09:00 AM. How would I compare it to my current time?

Comment: @YasirIjaz for that cases there is `TIME` field type, not `DATETIME` and not `DATE`. if You've `VARCHAR`, `CHAR`, `TEXT` which keeps `09:00 AM`  - so make sure You've comparable field type.  Find `->time` method to write schemas with `TIME` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#columns

Answer (score 0):

This would be the regular query

data = {some_id:1, time_1:'1970-01-01 07:00:00', time_2:'1970-01-01 07:00:00'}

```
$results = $this->model->select('table.value as value')
           ->where([
               ['table.some_id', '=', $data['some_id']],
               [function($query) use($data){
                  query->where('table.time_1', '=>', $data['time_1'])
                       ->orWhere('table.time_2', '<=', $data['time_2']);
               }]
             ])->get();
```

If you need to transform the date there's a function called `date()` this transforms timestamps into date with the given format. Ex:

```
$date = 1497454883;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);
```

date will be  "2017-06-14 23:00:00"

If you have any questions let me know.